# Fibonacci Sequence and Time taken

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Consider the following (incomplete) java code, which calculates the Fibonacci numbers

```
public int fib(int n){
    function++;
    if(n==0) return 0;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

Let Step(n) denote the number of function calls that the program uses to calculate Fib(n).

The question asks:

> It can be shown that Step(n) is roughly $1.61^n$
>
> Consider a computer C that can make 1, 000, 000 function calls a
>   second. Calculate how long time it will take the program to compute
>   Fib(100). A rough estimate is sufficient. hint: You may use the fact
>   that a year (of 365 days) has 31, 536, 000 seconds.

How would you go about working this out? If say fib(1) makes 1 function call, while fib(2) makes 3 function calls and then fib(3) makes 5 function calls etc...How on earth would you work out how many Fib(100) makes? Surely this number is going to be huge!

I of course could use a computer but it's a written question. Some advice/guidance would help as I don't want the answer, just a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: **Hint:** If $F(n)$ be the number of function calls made by `fib(n)`, then we have the following recurrence $F(n)=1+F(n-1)+F(n-2)~\forall~n\geq 2$. Try to solve this recurrence for the closed form of $F(n)$.

Comment: Also, to be precise, Step(n) is exactly given by $\phi^n$ where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). Can you prove this?

Comment: Would it be 1.6^100 divided by a million seconds? Which would give us the number of seconds taken? Or am I completely wrong

Comment: That's not Python!

Comment: @HansLundmark yeah sorry meant to write Java.

Comment: I solved the question thanks to @learner. It was 1.61^100 divided by a million divided by the number of seconds in a year.